# Преобразовать массив в тип данных c#

Tags: c#

// Как мне массив преоброзовать обратно в тип данных?
// Чтобы я мог эти данные использовать в цикле foreach

```
string[] dataType = {"int","float","decimal","double"};


        foreach (var dType in dataType)
        {
            WriteLine($"{sizeof(dType)} {dType.MaxValue} {dType.MinValue}");
        }
```

Код как пример он не работает!(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
class TypeInfo
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public object MinValue { get; }
    public object MaxValue { get; }
    public int InstanceSize { get; }

    public TypeInfo(Type type)
    {
        // validation...

        Name = type.FullName;
        InstanceSize = Marshal.SizeOf(type);
        MinValue = type.GetField("MinValue").GetValue(null);
        MaxValue = type.GetField("MaxValue").GetValue(null);
    }
}
```

```cs
static void Main()
{
    var typeNames = new[] { "Int32", "Double", "UInt16" };
    var rows = typeNames
        .Select(typeName => Type.GetType($"System.{typeName}")!) // можно объединить в 1
        .Select(type => new TypeInfo(type))                      //
        .Select(typeInfo => $@"{typeInfo.Name.Substring(7),-8}
 {typeInfo.Size,4} {typeInfo.MinValue,30} {typeInfo.MaxValue,30}");

    Console.WriteLine($"{"Name",-8} Size {"MinValue",30} {"MaxValue",30}");

    foreach (var row in rows)
        Console.WriteLine(row);
}
```

Comment: От Души Душевно В Душу)